# "command line argurment is not valid" error - only with Outlook. Creating email msg with PHP

Tags: php, outlook

I want the user to be able to click on a link that will open the desktop default email program and populate a new email message. The user can then further modify the email and send it. My coding has been working perfectly for more than a year. This still works fine with Thunderbird but recently, users with Outlook as their default email program have been receiving the following message:

"Cannot start Microsoft office outlook. The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using."

Anyone aware of this issue and hopefully it's solution? I assume I need to make a correction in my PHP coding that creates the link. Here's the guts of it:

```
echo '<td colspan=2><a href="';
echo 'mailto:'.$row[10].'?subject=Item Request&body='.$body;
echo '">Contact Owner</td>';
```

Comment: how big of a body are you passing in, and what kind of text is in it?

Comment: Are there quotes or \'s in the body?

Answer (score 0):

Path components for `mailto:` links need to be [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)d just like any other URL:

```
echo '<td colspan=2><a href="';
echo htmlspecialchars('mailto:'.urlencode($row[10]).'?subject=Item%20Request&body='.urlencode($body));
echo '">Contact Owner</td>';
```

Note that any dynamic string to be output on an HTML document also should be passed through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: As I said, this has been working for  a year+, and still works well with Thunderbird, so I think the PHP has been correct. Something has changed with Outlook in the last month or so, or perhaps the change is with an Add On?

Comment: @bobonwhidbey Have you tried this code? It sounds to me as if Outlook doesn't like the spaces(s) in the URL or this otherwise causes a syntax error. It may be that an update to Outlook has caused it to be more strict with the parsing of the arguments.

Comment: I made a very bad assumption that ALL web users would have an email program on their computer. Those days are well behind us. My approach of using a "mailto:" link to initiate email communication is less than ideal. A different approach is needed.